# Should I delete my upvoted answer?

Tags: discussion, support

**UPDATE:** The OP commented

> Thanks, this did the work

( I really don't know why), **BUT** I would appreciate to get an answer for the future.

I found some similar questions here, but I didn't find a question for this specific case.

I have [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33872534/5297359) this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33872456/5297359). I received 3 upvotes (yes I'm happy).

**My Answer:**

```
Maybe you can add the `{QUERY_STRING}`

    RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php?%{QUERY_STRING}

This should append all GET params to the new url.
```

**A user commented this:**

> By not including a query string (ie. a ?) in the substitution, the
>   query string on the request should already be passed through to the
>   substitution. Manually adding ?%{QUERY_STRING} is not required

**The problem is:**
The user who has commented on is definitely right (I've testet it).

I think this answer provides me a few reputation points **BUT** it's simply a wrong answer, because if you drop my approach (QUERY_STRING) you have exactly the same what is not working in OP's example.

So the question is: Should I delete it, because it's just wrong.

Comment: I'd suggest fixing the answer if possible except the OP claims it *did* solve their problem. Perhaps the OP didn't describe their problem properly?

Comment: @BSMP, the OP commented while i wrote this question. I've updated it. But in this case I could not fix the answer, because I thought it is correct until a user proved me wrong. So the question is still how to deal with an upvoted answer that is wrong. thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @user193661, well the problem is that I had upvotes before I *thought* it's not correct. I still don't know if it's correct, because it probably helped the OP

Comment: Would the other comment have come about if you hadn't posted your answer? Simply edit your answer to be correct and give a mention to the user that pointed out the mistake. If the other user was bothered about getting the points then they should have posted an answer.

Comment: @MacroMan, the thing is that the other user said I'm wrong ;) OP now said it helped. So the thing is, if the OP says it helps I won't delete it, because maybe there are more facts than I know (i.e. apache configuration,...). But I'm still interested how to deal with deleting own upvoted answers, if they are having no effect at all (at least for other users)

Comment: @swidmann I think the main thing is to consider the wider community and if it's helpful to them rather than just the OP. If it is - leave it, if not, then it's no use to anyone so by all means delete it.

Comment: @MacroMan: Sounds good, but how to determine if it's helpful to the community should i wait a few days/weeks and when there are no more upvotes, delete it?

Comment: @swidmann If it's getting upvotes - then surely that's the community telling you it's helpful? ;)

Comment: @MacroMan: probably not surely, but if I upvote some answer I used or I tried it, so it helped me. Sorry for bothering you again, but how should I know if this answer is really helpful?

Comment: If it's wrong, it isn't helpful. is the answer wrong?

Comment: The status of the question isn't clear. Just wait. If it doesn't get fixed, downvote the question and remove your answer.

Comment: @KevinB. it's like user193661 said: status is unclear, so think I'll just wait